# Odd clicking noise while attempting to play a sound in python

Tags: python

While working on a simple little timer I was creating to simultaneously help me learn more about Python and to help me keep on schedule with my schoolwork; I decided to add a little tune to let me know when your time was up. However, after using the following snippet of code to program each individual note:

```
winsound.Beep(Freq, Dur)
```

I realized that whenever I actually played the little song, an odd clicking sound happened between each note. Does anyone know what's going on? Should I use a different expression? Am I just losing my mind?

Edit: Since posting this, I realized what the issue is, the program is waiting about a sixteenth of second in between playing each note. So I'd like to ask another question (any answers relating to the others would still be appreciated), namely, how can I make it *not* wait in between the notes.

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(262,500)
winsound.Beep(277,500)
winsound.Beep(294,500)
winsound.Beep(311,500)
winsound.Beep(330,500)
winsound.Beep(349,500)
winsound.Beep(370,500)
winsound.Beep(392,500)
winsound.Beep(415,500)
winsound.Beep(440,500)
winsound.Beep(466,500)
winsound.Beep(493,500)
winsound.Beep(523,500)
```

All the above code does is play a simple chromatic scale from middle c to c2, but once one runs it, one would immediately see what Im talking about

Comment: Show us a bit more code for the "wait in between notes" question

Comment: @Splinxyy I added a simple chromatic scale; you'll see what I'm asking for help about if you run it...

Comment: Can't run it, I'm on a linux machine. It might just be the speed of Python holding you back, or the speed of winsound. Personally, I use `pygame` to play all my sounds, so you might want to take a look into that.

Comment: @Splinxyy Wow, this is *much* better, thanks so much for your help; though you didn't technically give me an answer, you gave me something much more useful!

Comment: No worries. With pygame, you can set the frequency and all sorts in the (pre) init. Check it all out [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)